# How to integrate Odoo lead creation api in ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, odoo

I am developing an application which is in swift and the backend is Odoo. Odoo apis calling is working fine using Alamofire. I have one issue with lead creation api. There is a format for product_id which is: **[(6,0,[123,234])]**. Here this format is not working if I pass it as a **String** and it is not accepted without as a string in JSON.
So can anyone tell me which type of format it is and how to pass it in post data?

Here is my code:

1. with Disctionary

```
let ids = selectedProducts.value(forKey: kId) as! NSArray
let productIds = NSMutableArray(capacity: 0)
productIds.add("[(6,0")
productIds.add("["+ids.componentsJoined(by: ",")+"])]")
saveDic[kProductId] = productIds.componentsJoined(by: ",")
```

2. with string:

```
let ids = selectedProducts.value(forKey: kId) as! NSArray
let productIds = NSMutableArray(capacity: 0)
productIds.add("[(6,0")
productIds.add("(6,0,["+ids.componentsJoined(by: ",")+"])")
let pid = "(6,0,["+ids.componentsJoined(by: ",")+"])"
postData += ", \"" + kProductId + "\" : [" + pid + "]"
```

Thank you